# Prestashop multistor: moved to root, now "share Customers" And "share Orders" are broken

Tags: prestashop

After moving my development shop to root for live access everything works except for this multistore "share Customers" And "share Orders" thing.

**Old setup:** all shops use the same domain but have a different virtual url.
**Live setup:** each shop has a unique domain with no more virtual uri's.

**Cpanel:** addon domains are used. They work. The shops display nicely, all products work but the cart and users aren't shared amongst the shops anymore. As this is a key feature I'm now totally blocked by this incident.

I'm trying to figure out how to circumvent this (must be in DB somewhere, right?) but I'm wasting so much time, maybe someone knows what to do? I'm not urning cache but I still manually delete it from time to time and also browser cache is cleared and I test on multiple browsers.

what I've tried:
- disable/enable multistore;
- regenerate htaccess;
- removed all orders, carts, users
All the while removing cache regularly after settings are changed.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing "Customers and carts" you mean logged in customer in store #1 is also logged in in store #2? To be honest I didn't saw such a setup with PrestaShop, virtual uri is something totally different becaues you still operate on the same domain, different domains needs proper configuration with many things related to sessions, cookies etc.

Comment: yeah apparently there is no built-in multidomain support, I had to buy an addon for that (which doesn't work yet, might as well trydoing it myself)